# How to set DEBUG log level for ResourceManager?

Tags: hadoop, logging, log4j, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I am doing some change to Yarn source code. I have changed `hadoop.root.logger=DEBUG,console` to DEBUG in `${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop/log4j.properties`. I can get DEBUG information for Application Master, but I can't find any DEBUG information outputted in `${HADOOP_HOME}/logs/yarn-yar-resourcemanager-hostname.log`. Is there any other place I should change to trigger DEBUG level for resourcemanager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Setting debug log level for individual daemons](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.hadoop.user/48352):

> Add `-Dhadoop.root.logger=DEBUG` to something like `HADOOP_resourcemanager_opts` in `yarn-env.sh`

Answer (score 2):

etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

search below line

## export HADOOP_DAEMON_ROOT_LOGGER=INFO,RFA

for daemon, change INFO,RFA to DEBUG,RFA
for interactive process, there is another default setting above, change it

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to add in `yarn-env.sh`

```
YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -Dhadoop.root.logger=${YARN_ROOT_LOGGER:-DEBUG,console}"
YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -Dyarn.root.logger=${YARN_ROOT_LOGGER:-DEBUG,console}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For YARN daemons started using `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh`, you should update the `YARN_ROOT_LOGGER` log level in that script.

Answer (score 0):

Try with. It should enabled yarn level debug logging.

```
export YARN_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,RFA
```